# When I try to select MAX(id) it returns 99

Tags: mysql, sql

//Excuse my english
I want to select the greatest id in my 'client 'table (which has 383 clients, that means 383 it's the largest id), but when I make the query it returns '99'.

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM clients";
```

I don't know what to do. My objective is to add 1 to de latest id to make a new id for a new client.

Comment: While Gordon's solution will get you what you need at the moment, you really should change your ID to be an integer instead of a string. Also, look into `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my ID. I didn't notice that when i created the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `id` is being stored as a string (probably).

You can use silent conversion to get the max:

```
select max(id + 0)
from clients;
```

Alternatively, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id
from clients
order by length(id) desc, id desc
limit 1;
```